# tokbox iPhone Incompatible Browser

Tags: ios, reactjs, tokbox

I'm working on Audio Publishing project which use `tokbox api`. Application works fine on most of the device but getting `Incompatible Browser` when use Chrome, Firefox.

Safari work but the Chrome and firefox showing the error.
Tested device-

- iPhone 6 : Safari works, issue with Chrome and Firefox
- iPhone x : Safari works, issue with Chrome and Firefox
- iPhone xs: Safari works, issue with Chrome and Firefox

As I'm unable to debug chrome console on those devices, not getting any clue the root cause of that problem.
Looking for help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox iOS applications use the iOS Safari WebView under the hood. In iOS 11 the WebView does not have access to the microphone and camera. 
For more info, check the article about this subject: https://support.tokbox.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001586430-Chrome-Firefox-iOS-applications-do-not-work-with-OpenTok.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks you Chomu. I read that article before. Do you think HLS or RTMP will work on this?